# MVC AngularJS date field unable to edit

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-model

My HTML for date field is

```
<input class="form-control"type="text" name="txtOrderContractFinishDate" id="txtOrderContractFinishDate" ng-model="SelectedOrder.OrderContractFinishDate  | jsDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
```

jsDate function is as below

```
app.filter("jsDate", function () {
    return function (x) {
        return new Date(parseInt(x.substr(6)));
    };
});
```

the date gets converted from JSON date format to `MMddyyy` format without any problem.  But once after data is displayed if I try to edit the date field it is not allowing me to do so. I am new to angularjs. Can anyone help, please ?

Comment: Can you create plunker/fiddle/codepen code snippet of your code? it would be easy to debug

Comment: That won't work because the filter returns a new value but you need to retain two way binding on your model property `SelectedOrder.OrderContractFinishDate`. Try using a library like ng-mask to accomplish this in a different fashion.